# Find MLE on custom density function

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

> Let $y_1,\dots,y_n$ be i.i.d. random variables from
>   $$p_{Y_i}(y_i;\alpha,\beta)=exp\{y_i(\alpha+\beta x_i)-ln(1-e^{\alpha+\beta y_i})\},\ y_i=0,1$$
>
> $\alpha, \beta$ are unknown real parameters and $x_i$ are known.
>
> I need to find the likelihood and log-likelihood for $\theta=(\alpha,\beta)$ and also the MLE for $\theta$.

I started from:

$$L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}exp\{y_i(\alpha+\beta x_i)-ln(1-e^{\alpha+\beta y_i})\}$$

$$l(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_i(\alpha+\beta x_i)-ln(1-e^{\alpha+\beta y_i})\right)$$

Now, the score function $l_{*}(\theta)$ shuold be

$$l_{*}(\theta)=\left(\frac{\partial{l(\alpha,\beta)}}{\partial\alpha},\ \frac{\partial{l(\alpha,\beta)}}{\partial\beta}\right)$$

and for MLE $l_{*}(\theta)=0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The log-likelihood doesn't look right. Also, this problem might not have a closed form solution but you can use an iterative procedure.

Comment: @JohnK Hi, why is wrong the log-likelihood?